# dayClick not working as expected in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

If clicked on the date number it should show, `Clicked on the day`. But no matter where I click it is always going to else `Clicked Everywhere`. What's wrong?

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    if (allDay) {
        if ($(jsEvent.target).is('div.fc-day-number')) {
            alert('Clicked on the day');
        }
        else{
            alert('Clicked everywhere');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not clear! What do you mean by Clicked Everywhere?

Comment: See my else condition statement. `If clicked on the date I want to show Clicked on the day if clicked on the whole slot or anywhere I want to show Clicked Everywhere`. But Even if I click on the `date` it shows `Clicked everywhere`

Comment: Oh my mistake. BTW your code work fine for me. Clicking on day number i got `alert('Clicked on the day');`

Comment: I don't know what's the problem, it's not working fine on mine.

Comment: It turns out `selectDay` and `dayClicked` won't work on the same calendar.